# How to forward a TSDoc description within an object property

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsdoc

For example, I have a function:

```
/**
 * Function returns null
 */
const myFunction = () => {
  return null
}
```

And an object like this:

```
const internals = {
  myFunction: myFunction,
}
```

So I want to see this description: "Function returns null" at `internals.myFunction` in VScode.

But with notations like @inheritDoc, @link and such I just see them as is: `{@inheritDoc myFunction}`

I want to generate a solid `d.ts` with all necessary docs

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

So I had a glance at React sources and there is the way:

Let assume the function is in a file `my-function.ts`:

```
/**
 * Function returns null
 */
export const myFunction = () => {
  return null
}
```

then I reexport all my functions like this:

`functions.ts`:

```
import {myFunction} from './my-function'
import {myFunction2} from './my-function2'
// and other imports

export {
  myFunction,
  myFunction2,
}
```

And finally:

`internals.ts`

```
import * as functions from './functions'

const internals = {
  functions,
}
```

So by this way I finally can see "Function returns null" at

```
internals.functions.myFunction
```

[So check my codesandbox for the example](https://codesandbox.io/s/reexport-tsdoc-definitions-93t4c?file=/src/index.ts)